# Как сделать прогресс бар в консоли, отражающий процесс скачивания одного единственного файла с сервера в папку на жестком диске?

Tags: php, файлы, консоль, клиент-сервер

Такая проблема: есть функция, которая по url скачивает с сайта один, но очень большой файл (5 гб).

```
private function getFileInOurFolder()
    {
        $path = $_ENV["conf"]["database_saving_folder"];
        $url =  $_ENV["conf"]["source"]["link"] . $this->fileName . ".json.zip";
        file_put_contents(__DIR__.$path.'database.json.zip', fopen($url, 'r'));
    }
```

Так как скрипт существенное время висит на выполнении этого действия, хочу в консоли сделать прогресс бар. К сожалению, в интернете все примеры посвящены циклу, в котором состояние прогресс бара определяется пройденными итерациями. Но у меня один файл и никакого цикла. Требуется просто отразить прогресс выполнения file_put_contents от начала и до конца. Опытные специалисты, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? Пробовал самостоятельно что-то придумать, но нужна какая-то точка начала и конца, а как выхватить конец выполнения стандартной функции php, у которой все спрятано "под капотом"..

Comment: Смотрите ответ в [англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292472/download-files-file-put-contents-with-progress)

Comment: Спасибо! Вариант по ссылке кажется наиболее приемлемым..